# Allocating Java 12.0.1 memory space using -Xmx not working, -d64 not recognized

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, debian, java-12

I am currently running a GCP server utilizing Debian 9 and Java 12.0.1. I've been trying to allocate 7GB of RAM to the java server using `-Xms1G -Xmx7G` on startup however when stress testing the server and running `free -m` in the background, I haven't seen Java utilizing more than exactly 1.75GB of RAM, even when under immense stress.

I was previously using `-d64` to specify 64-bit Java with my old version of Java (openJDK 1.8 I believe?), however since upgrading to Java 12.0.1, I get an error when trying to use `-d64`, `Unrecognized option: -d64`.

My current VM has 7.5GB of RAM. Running `uname -a` gave me the following:

`Linux server-name 4.9.0-8-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.144-3.1 (2019-02-19) x86_64 GNU/Linux`

**Edit:** Following up on a comment, see results of `ulimit -a` below.
[image]

Comment: I am wondering: Maybe a limit is set? Check the output of "ulimit -a" to see if limits are set for memory usage of single processes?

Comment: For simplicity's sake I took a screenshot and appended it to the original post. I'm not sure how to interpret all of this, but it doesn't seem too out of the ordinary.

Comment: Ok, that looks good and is not the reason that the memory is limited.

Comment: Just on `-d64`. That option has been obsolete and deprecated since JDK 8 and removed in JDK 10.

Comment: @AlanBateman …and `-d64` never had any meaning on Linux anyway, as `-d32` and `-d64` never were supported on other systems than Solaris.

Comment: Is there any indicator that the stress test should raise the memory consumption? Do you get any `OutOfMemoryError`s?